# Чтобы сработало событие touchmove нужно обязательно кликнуть на элемент?

Tags: javascript, mobile-development, touch-event

пытаюсь реализовать перемещение элемента на сенсорных экранах, но при попытке потянуть элемент он никак не реагирует. Перемещение срабатывает только если предварительно кликнуть на этот элемент. Подскажите в чем может быть ошибка

```js
var marker = document.querySelector('.cap__square');
var onStart = function(startEvt) {
    startEvt.preventDefault();
var onMove = function(e) {
    let slideBlock = document.querySelector('.cap__block');
    let pageX = e.changedTouches[0].clientX - block.getBoundingClientRect().left - square.clientWidth;
    let pageXRight = e.changedTouches[0].clientX - block.getBoundingClientRect().left - 2;
    if (pageX > -1 && pageXRight < slideBlock.clientWidth) {
        pazl.style.left = pageX + 'px';
        square.style.left = pageX + 'px';
        square.style.top = unplashImgHeight + 11 +'px';
    } else {
        square.addEventListener('touchend') = function() {
            document.removeEventListener('touchmove', onMouseMove);
            square.onmouseup = null;
        };
    }
};
var onEnd = function(endEvt) {
    window.removeEventListener('touchmove', onMove);
    window.removeEventListener('touchend', onEnd);
    marker.removeEventListener('touchstart', onStart);
};
window.addEventListener('touchmove', onMove, true);
window.addEventListener('touchend', onEnd, true);
};
marker.addEventListener('touchstart', onStart, true);
```

```html
<div class="cap__block">
    <div class="cap__square">
        <img src="img/icon/arrow.svg" class="img-svg cap__arrow" alt="">\
    </div>
</div>
```